# Process with increments that are stationary but not independent

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples

I wanted to find an example of a process with increments that are stationary but not independent.

I first thought that noticed that a constant sequence $X_t=X$ but the increments are then all equal to zero so they are independent.

The other stationary processes I know are Poisson point process and Lévy process that both have independent increments. Can someone provide a good example ?

Comment: $X_t=tX$ is such a  process.